# How to change variable into symbol?

Tags: ruby, variables, symbols

I need to put variable values from hash into another hash as **symbol.** 
Is this the best way to do that?

```
v="a value from loop."
p new_hash_key=:"#{v}".to_s

=> a value from loop
```

Comment: Hash keys can be strings; they don't have to be symbols.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to make a symbol from your string then use `.to_sym` method:

```
> v="a value from loop."
 => "a value from loop." 
> v.to_sym
 => :"a value from loop."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v = "a value from loop."
p new_hash_key=v.to_sym
```